# Spyder console self defined module not updated

Tags: python-2.7, import, console, spyder

I import a function from a self defined module in spyder console as:

```
from self import ver1
```

now if i edit the self and add a ver2 function and do this:

```
from self import ver2
```

I get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name ver2
```

I have tried this: (i delete the self.pyc file and regenerate it)

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("self.py")
```

but it still does not work. However if I close and reopen spyder, it does work. Is there any other getaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the module as it has already been imported. You can do that using the python built-in `reload` function. 
Besides, if the Spyder console that you use is an IPython console, you can use the autoreload IPython magic.

```
% load_ext autoreload
% autoreload 2
```

You can set up Spyder to run this automatically on startup of a new ipython console in Spyder preferences.

Comment: Doing this: 

    "reload(ver2)"

gave the following error: "reload() argument must be a module"

Whereas, doing this: 

    "type(ver2)"

gives: <type 'function'>

... So I guess my question is how do I reload or refresh a function.